# What is Gameshare, and what should I do if I did?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I'm pretty sure I Gameshared, but I'm not 100% sure: I don't fully understand what Gameshare means or if I did it. Could someone explain it to me?

#### Background

I'll start from the beginning: I have a PS4 and had GTA 5 from a few years ago. Fast forward a couple of years, I am now somehow able to download GTA on the PSN store (so I no longer needed the disc). I didn't do it on purpose, I just found a way go get it on the PSN store.

I had the disc of the games I downloaded on the PSN store. I gave the disks to my friend who didn't have GTA and he downloaded it on his PS4. He told me he only played it once, for a short period of time, and only GTA Online, not story mode.

I did the same for Black ops 3: I found a way to get it on the PSN store and I gave the disk to him, but again he said that he only played it once. For Far Cry: Primal, he said he got pretty far in that game. I didn't really ever play Far Cry Primal, but I still played GTA and Black Ops 3 after he got the disks. I guess he sold all the disk for $26.

---

I'm just really scared I accidentally gameshared. This happened almost a year ago and I had no idea this could be illegal, or I could get banned for it. If I gameshared I would be very guilty and want to report myself to Sony, pathetic I know it's just the type of person I am. Now that I know I will not ever do it again I have learned from my mistakes but I never knew I was making a mistake until today.

Anyways, could someone please explain what Gameshare is and if that's what I did, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

So as a summary: you bought a couple of games, you then downloaded those games from the PSN store and gave your games to your brother, and now you're worried you broke some sort of rule that states you can't share games with others.

Relax, there's nothing to worry about. Physical Playstation disks aren't linked to an account, so you're free to give them to other people if you're done playing them. In fact, your brother can play GTA Online without problems on his PS4, assuming he has a separate PSN account with an active PSPlus subscription. GTA Online progress is linked to the PSN/Rockstar account, not the physical disk. The same applies to the other games. You didn't break any Playstation rules.

Note that Playstation Gameshare is actually an entirely different system where you can connect to your PSN account on another Playstation as a secondary account so the owner of that Playstation can play the games linked to your PSN account. Again, this is completely legal and above board.

Comment: Even if I'm not done with the game, is it still ok to give it to other people? And thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @GaryZenger The game you downloaded from PSN is separate from the game you gifted to your brother. As mentioned, physical games aren't linked to PSN, so the copies of the games you downloaded probably came through a promotion of sorts. Those games are linked to your PSN account, so as long as you have that account and are subscribed to PS+, you can use those without owning the physical copies.

Comment: now i see the situation... yeah this is correct. gameshare in general is legal until piracy is involved

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the games were at some point the free game of the month for PS+ members.  I'm certain BlackOps III was as that's how I have it, not so sure about GTAV (that one I purchased).  You probably grabbed them without thinking about it, then later discovered you somehow had the "digital version" as well as your disc version, in which case you are completely within your rights to give away (or sell, etc.) the disc version and keep using your digital version.  It will of course only work for as long as you maintain your PS+ subscription, but otherwise you should be fine.